# Amplify tiny voltages accurately

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

[image]

Hi all, above is a **Schering's Bridge as a capacitance meter**. Following the equation below, Rx resistor is fixed, whereas for capacitor Cx can be placed with an unknown value capacitor. R1 will be adjusted until voltage across R4 will be 0. The problem is that the **voltage fluctuation across R4 when measuring capacitance value of is in maybe 10mV (0.01V) sensitivity and I am unsure if non-inverting op-amp amplifier  can have a 0.01V sensitivity for its voltage input?** So to sum it up, is there **a good way that we can amplify tiny voltages (0.01V) accurately** using any other method besides op amp?

Comment: Why do you think an opamp won't amplify 10mV?

Comment: You could use an instrumentation amplifier if you want to avoid drawing current from the circuit and thereby altering the result.

Comment: 10mV @1kHz is a massive signal and very easy to deal with using common op-amps.

Comment: Yeah, 10mV is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the very old LM741 can have a gain ~ 1000 at 1kHz that can be reduced to 100 for a 1V output with high SNR.

Some have much more. This is not a problem if a balanced Differential amplifier config. is used with twisted pairs.

I would suggest ones with JFET front ends to avoid loading effects, unless you are working with < 10pF ranges.